# Configuring Spring embedded LDAP server in CAS War Overlay server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cas, spring-ldap

I am trying to configure a CAS WAR overlay server for testing
https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/index.html

I want to startup a Spring LDAP embedded server with this:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("")
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=Groups")
                .groupSearchFilter("(uniqueMember={0})")
                .userDetailsContextMapper(new InetOrgPersonContextMapper())
                .contextSource(contextSource())
                .passwordCompare()
                    .passwordAttribute("telephoneNumber")
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:" + LDAP_PORT + "/"), "dc=jbcpcalendar,dc=com");
    }

}
```

and have the following configuration for the ldif config file to use

~/cas-server/cas/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
spring:
  ldap:
    embedded:
      ldif: classpath:/ldif/calendar.ldif
      baseDn: dc=jbcpcalendar,dc=com
      port: ${LDAP_PORT:33389}
#      credential:
#        username: user
#        password: secret
```

I am using the Gradle War overlay CAS project, and only trying to add LDAP.

When I added the above configuration file (SecurityConfig.java) to ~/cas-server/cas/src/main/java/*

When I add these dependencies:

```
subprojects {

    dependencies {

            compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-ldap:${project.'cas.version'}"

        // LDAP:
        // Not sure if I need and/or want this starter:
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:${project.'springboot.version'}")

        compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.3.1.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:4.2.3.RELEASE")
        // Due to a artifact resolution issue with Gradle,
        // spring-tx must be pulled in or Gradle will fetch an older one that doesn’t work.
        compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
        compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")

        // Security:
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    }
```

to ~/cas-server/build.gradle I get this error:

```
06:16:37.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
06:16:37.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'chapter10.00-cas-server'.
06:16:37.706 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap:1.5.3.RELEASE] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

When I add these dependencies:

```
            compile "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-ldap:${project.'cas.version'}"

        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
        compile("org.codehaus.groovy:groovy")

        // LDAP:
        // Not sure if I need and/or want this starter:
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap")

        compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:2.3.1.RELEASE")
        compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:4.2.3.RELEASE")
        // Due to a artifact resolution issue with Gradle,
        // spring-tx must be pulled in or Gradle will fetch an older one that doesn’t work.
        compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
        compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")


        // Security:
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
```

to ~/cas-server/cas/build.gradle I get this error:

```
    06:24:57.567 [QUIET] [system.out] 
    06:24:57.644 [QUIET] [system.out]    __   ____      _      ____   __  
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out]   / /  / ___|    / \    / ___|  \ \ 
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out]  | |  | |       / _ \   \___ \   | |
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out]  | |  | |___   / ___ \   ___) |  | |
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out]  | |   \____| /_/   \_\ |____/   | |
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out]   \_\                           /_/ 
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] 
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] CAS Version: 5.1.2
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] CAS Commit Id: fae163b426ba91cc78a18e3805b2f2fac9c03b2e
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] CAS Build Date/Time: 2017-09-20T12:19:37Z
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] Spring Boot Version: 1.5.3.RELEASE
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] ------------------------------------------------------------
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] System Date/Time: 2017-09-20T06:24:57.372
    06:24:57.645 [QUIET] [system.out] System Temp Directory: /var/folders/vm/nx7j7v8x4db1f4xsztj_rsmm0000gn/T/
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] ------------------------------------------------------------
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] Java Home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] Java Vendor: Oracle Corporation
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] Java Version: 1.8.0_144
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] JCE Installed: no
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] ------------------------------------------------------------
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] OS Architecture: x86_64
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] OS Name: Mac OS X
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] OS Version: 10.12.6
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] ------------------------------------------------------------
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] Apache Tomcat Version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] ------------------------------------------------------------
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] 
    06:24:57.646 [QUIET] [system.out] 
    06:24:57.833 [QUIET] [system.out] 2017-09-20 06:24:57.833  INFO 17183 --- [           main] .CasCoreBootstrapStandaloneConfiguration : Configuration files found at [/etc/cas/config] are [[/etc/cas/config/application.yml, /etc/cas/config/cas.properties]]
    06:24:57.852 [QUIET] [system.out] 2017-09-20 06:24:57.852  INFO 17183 --- [           main] .CasCoreBootstrapStandaloneConfiguration : Found and loaded [14] setting(s) from [/etc/cas/config]
    06:24:57.852 [QUIET] [system.out] 2017-09-20 06:24:57.852  INFO 17183 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: PropertiesPropertySource {name='standaloneCasConfigService'}
    06:25:00.680 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
    06:25:00.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:00.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:00.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:00.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:00.681 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:00.682 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
    06:25:01.171 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
    06:25:01.171 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] **Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)**
```

I have have not seen docs talking about embedded ldap servers, and I have looked at:
https://apereo.github.io/2017/03/24/cas51-ldapauthnjasypt-tutorial/
https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html

But certainly dont know where case.properties is supposed to be placed, and adding it to:
`~/cas-server/src/main/resources/cas.properties`

nor

`~/cas-server/cas/src/main/resources/cas.properties`

seemed to have any effect.

Other than that, I have not changed anything with the original project download.

I am really struggling with this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off to use Docker for this. Put together a docker-compose file that simply spins up an embedded ldap server and then also spins up a CAS server that connects to the ldap.

Here is an example to get you started:
https://github.com/mmoayyed/dockerized-idp-testbed

You need to connect the cas-server with the running ldap and remove all other components from compose.